# Convert Tiff to pdf with PDFSharp-gdi C#

Tags: c#, pdf, tiff, pdfsharp, image-transcoding

I am stuck. Currently I am trying to simulate pulling a binary blob from a database that is supposed to be a TIFF image. I use this gist [image.tif](https://gist.github.com/ozfive/dd14f125924d8eb937dc2ded756ef218) in the image variable to do so. I am pretty sure I am close to making this happen. It's that the issue probably has to do with how I am converting the string to byte array or something. Basically this application throws an exception stating that it can't create a PDF with 0 frames. At this point I must admit that I may be in over my head on this one. Could someone be so kind and help me the rest of the way with this one?

The code is included below:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Text;

namespace ConvertTifToPDFFile
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string image = "";

            byte[] imageAsByteStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(image);

            int imageByteStreamLength = imageAsByteStream.Length;

            string base64EncodedImage = Convert.ToBase64String(imageAsByteStream);

            imageAsByteStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64EncodedImage);

            Stream imageStream = TiffImageSplitter.ByteArrayToMemoryStream(imageAsByteStream);
            // Image splitImage = TiffImageSplitter.getTiffImage(imageStream, 1);
            TiffImageSplitter.tiff2PDF(imageStream);


        }
    }

    public class TiffImageSplitter
    {
        private static TiffImageSplitter tiff = new TiffImageSplitter();

        public static void tiff2PDF(Stream imageByteStream)
        {

            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

            int pageCount = getPageCount(imageByteStream);

            for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
            {
                PdfPage page = new PdfPage();
                Image img = getTiffImage(imageByteStream, 1);
                XImage imgFrame = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(img);

                page.Width = imgFrame.PointWidth;
                page.Height = imgFrame.PointHeight;
                doc.Pages.Add(page);

                XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[i]);

                xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
            }

            doc.Save("C:/temp/test.pdf");

            doc.Close();

        }


        public static Image getTiffImage(Stream imageStream, int pageNumber)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = null;
            Image returnImage = null;

            try
            {
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                Image sourceImage = Image.FromStream(imageStream, true, true);

                Guid objGuid = sourceImage.FrameDimensionsList[0];

                FrameDimension objDimension = new FrameDimension(objGuid);

                sourceImage.SelectActiveFrame(objDimension, pageNumber);

                sourceImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Tiff);

                returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
                returnImage = null;
            }

            return returnImage;
        }

        public static MemoryStream ByteArrayToMemoryStream(byte[] bytestream)
        {

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            stream.Write(bytestream, 0, bytestream.Length);

            return stream;
        }

        public static int getPageCount(Stream imageStream)
        {
            int pageCount = -1;
            try
            {
                Image img = Image.FromStream(imageStream, true, true);
                pageCount = img.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
                img.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
                pageCount = 0;
            }

            return pageCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you make a BASE64 encoding (among several other things I do not understand).

Comment: I was trying to see if I needed to decode or encode the string to make it valid.

Comment: To me it looks like a HEX-encoded string which should be decoded to binary format.

Comment: Can you suggest how I would decode the hex to binary?

Comment: Your hex string isn't valid, it should have an even number of characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**IMPORTANT!!!! First of all, your example tiff isn't valid at all**. It can't be read by any file editor. I have had to take [these ones](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/sample/) for testing.

Then, the code has couple errors:

1) I don't understand what've done with strings but reading files and BLOBs are same:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //string image = "";

            //byte[] imageAsByteStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(image);

            byte[] imageAsByteStream = File.ReadAllBytes("../../../MARBIBM.TIF");

            //int imageByteStreamLength = imageAsByteStream.Length;

            //string base64EncodedImage = Convert.ToBase64String(imageAsByteStream);

            //imageAsByteStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64EncodedImage);

            Stream imageStream = TiffImageSplitter.ByteArrayToMemoryStream(imageAsByteStream);
            // Image splitImage = TiffImageSplitter.getTiffImage(imageStream, 1);
            TiffImageSplitter.tiff2PDF(imageStream);


        }
```

2) method `tiff2PDF` should be like that

```
        public static void tiff2PDF(Stream imageByteStream)
        {

            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

            int pageCount = getPageCount(imageByteStream);

            for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
            {
                PdfPage page = new PdfPage();
                Image img = getTiffImage(imageByteStream, i); //<---HERE WAS ANOTHER ERROR, LOOK AT i
                XImage imgFrame = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(img);
```

3)

```
        public static MemoryStream ByteArrayToMemoryStream(byte[] bytestream)
        {

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytestream);
            //stream.Write(bytestream, 0, bytestream.Length); 

            return stream;
        }
```